# Producer error in Scala Embedded Kafka with Kafka Streams

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, embedded-kafka

I have a test that temperamentally leaves an open producer thread with a continuous error logging.

```
[2018-06-01 15:52:48,526] WARN [Producer clientId=test-deletion-stream-application-9d94ddd6-6f29-4364-890e-0d9676782edd-StreamThread-1-producer] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2018-06-01 15:52:48,526] WARN [Producer clientId=test-deletion-stream-application-9d94ddd6-6f29-4364-890e-0d9676782edd-StreamThread-1-producer] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2018-06-01 15:52:48,526] WARN [Producer clientId=test-deletion-stream-application-9d94ddd6-6f29-4364-890e-0d9676782edd-StreamThread-1-producer] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2018-06-01 15:52:48,628] WARN [Producer clientId=test-deletion-stream-application-9d94ddd6-6f29-4364-890e-0d9676782edd-StreamThread-1-producer] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2018-06-01 15:52:48,628] WARN [Producer clientId=test-deletion-stream-application-9d94ddd6-6f29-4364-890e-0d9676782edd-StreamThread-1-producer] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2018-06-01 15:52:48,628] WARN [Producer clientId=test-deletion-stream-application-9d94ddd6-6f29-4364-890e-0d9676782edd-StreamThread-1-producer] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2018-06-01 15:52:48,730] WARN [Producer clientId=test-deletion-stream-application-9d94ddd6-6f29-4364-890e-0d9676782edd-StreamThread-1-producer] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2018-06-01 15:52:48,730] WARN [Producer clientId=test-deletion-stream-application-9d94ddd6-6f29-4364-890e-0d9676782edd-StreamThread-1-producer] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2018-06-01 15:52:48,730] WARN [Producer clientId=test-deletion-stream-application-9d94ddd6-6f29-4364-890e-0d9676782edd-StreamThread-1-producer] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2018-06-01 15:52:48,982] WARN [Producer clientId=test-deletion-stream-application-9d94ddd6-6f29-4364-890e-0d9676782edd-StreamThread-1-producer] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2018-06-01 15:52:48,982] WARN [Producer clientId=test-deletion-stream-application-9d94ddd6-6f29-4364-890e-0d9676782edd-StreamThread-1-producer] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2018-06-01 15:52:48,982] WARN [Producer clientId=test-deletion-stream-application-9d94ddd6-6f29-4364-890e-0d9676782edd-StreamThread-1-producer] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

The test works, but sometimes fails like above.

```
test("My test") {
  val topology = Application.getTopology(...)
  val streams = new KafkaStreams(topology,properties)

  withRunningKafka {
    createCustomTopic(eventTopic)
    val streamId = UUIDs.newUuid().toString
    logger.info(s"Creating stream with Application ID: [$streamId]")
    val streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, streamConfig(streamId, PropertiesConfig.asScalaMap(props)))

    try {
      publishToKafka(eventTopic, key = keyMSite1UID1, message = event11a)
      // ... several more publishings
      Thread.sleep(publishingDelay) // Give time to initialize
      streams.start()
      Thread.sleep(deletionDelay)

      withConsumer[MyKey, MyEvent, Unit] { consumer =>
        val consumedMessages: Stream[(MyKey, MyEvent)] =
          consumer.consumeLazily[(MyKey, MyEvent)](eventTopic)
        val messages = consumedMessages.take(20).toList
        messages.foreach(tuple => logger.info("EVENT   END: " + tuple))
        messages.size should be(6)
        // several assertions here
      }
    } finally {
      streams.close()
    }
  }(config)
}
```

A particularity is that the streams application produces deletion events over the same topic it consumes from.

There are two similar tests in this suite. I execute the test suite under sbt, like so:

```
testOnly *MyTest
```

Four out of five executions leave a dangling thread posting those errors indefinitely. They appear in groups of 3, but I don't know why either.

I've tried setting delays after calls to close(), but it does not seem to help.
How to avoid dangling Producer threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test, you are creating two `KafkaStreams` instances, but you only `close()` one. I assume that the lacking `Producer` belongs to the instance you don't close. Note, that you need to call `KafkaStreams#close()` even if you never called `KafkaStreams#start()`.